# Can we fill across columns with new fields in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that has multiple values in the same row/column.  Some are separated by "-".  I am trying to split the columns appropriately and then add the values that are implied by the "-".  I've been able to get the dataset into the right format, but I am not having success in finding a way to create a sequence between `lower` and `upper`.

sample data set here (UPDATE:  Actual data set has 'codes' with alpha characters):

```
grp_id <- ("grp1")
name <- ("test")
code <- ("93790, 93797 - 93798, 98960 - 98962, 98966 - 98968, 99078, G1501, G5017")
df <- data.frame(grp_id, name, code)
```

what I have tried:

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(code, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  separate(code, sep = "-", into = c("lower", "upper")) %>%
  mutate(upper = case_when(is.na(upper) ~ lower,
                           TRUE ~ upper)) %>%
  mutate(implied = seq(as.numeric(lower), as.numeric(upper), by = 1))
```

this works great until the last `mutate` where I try to create new columns for the new values.

The expected output would be :

```
group_id  name  lower   upper implied.1  implied.2    rn
grp1      test   97390   97390  na        na          1
grp1      test   97397   97398  na        na          2
grp1      test   98960   98962  *98961*   na          3
grp1      test   G1501                                4
grp1      test   G5017                                5
```

So you can see in rn 3 the 98961 was added as it was the implied value by the "-".

Any suggestions I can try?

EDIT:  Since my actual data set has some alpha characters, this solution doesn't completely work.  I have edited as below, however it breaks down at the last mutate function.

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(code, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  separate(code, sep = "-", into = c("lower", "upper")) %>%
  mutate(upper = case_when(is.na(upper) ~ lower,
                           TRUE ~ upper)) %>%
  mutate(lower = case_when(
    str_detect(as.character(lower), '\\D') ~ lower,
    TRUE ~ as.character(as.numeric(lower))), 
    upper = case_when(
      str_detect(as.character(lower), '\\D') ~ lower,
      TRUE ~ as.character(as.numeric(upper)))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(implied = list( seq(lower, upper, by = 1))) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest_wider(implied)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dplyr::rowwise to create a tibble grouped by row, then make sure to wrap your seq statement in a list. Then use tidyr::unnest_wider to unnest the list, to get each value in the sequence in its own column. You could then just rename the columns with rename or rename_at.

Does this work for your needs?

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(code, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  separate(code, sep = "-", into = c("lower", "upper")) %>%
  mutate(upper = case_when(is.na(upper) ~ lower,
                           TRUE ~ upper)) %>%
  mutate(lower = as.numeric(lower), upper = as.numeric(upper)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(implied = list( seq(lower, upper, by = 1)) ) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest_wider(implied)
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 8
  grp_id name  lower upper    rn  ...1  ...2  ...3
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 grp1   test  93790 93790     1 93790    NA    NA
2 grp1   test  93797 93798     2 93797 93798    NA
3 grp1   test  98960 98962     3 98960 98961 98962
4 grp1   test  98966 98968     4 98966 98967 98968
5 grp1   test  99078 99078     5 99078    NA    NA
```

UPDATE to handle alpha characters:

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(code, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  separate(code, sep = "-", into = c("lower", "upper")) %>% 
  mutate(lower = str_trim(lower),
         upper = str_trim(upper),
         alpha = str_extract(lower, "[A-Z]+"),
         lower = parse_number(lower),
         upper = case_when(
           !is.na(alpha) ~ as.character(NA),
           is.na(upper) ~ as.character(lower),
           TRUE ~ as.character(upper)
         ),
         upper = as.numeric(upper)
  ) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(implied = ifelse(
    is.na(alpha), list( seq(lower, upper, by = 1)), NA
      )
    ) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest_wider(implied) %>% 
  unite(alpha, lower, col = lower, sep = "", na.rm = TRUE)
```

```
# A tibble: 7 x 8
  grp_id name  lower upper    rn  ...1  ...2  ...3
  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 grp1   test  93790 93790     1 93790    NA    NA
2 grp1   test  93797 93798     2 93797 93798    NA
3 grp1   test  98960 98962     3 98960 98961 98962
4 grp1   test  98966 98968     4 98966 98967 98968
5 grp1   test  99078 99078     5 99078    NA    NA
6 grp1   test  G1501    NA     6    NA    NA    NA
7 grp1   test  G5017    NA     7    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: My actual data set has some fields with alpha characters.  (I updated the sample data set above).  These convert to NA's.  Any ideas on how to keep them in?

Comment: Hmm. Can you update the expected output? Do you want all of the numbers between G1501 and G5017?

Comment: Updated the expected output.  There shouldn't be any case where there are alphanumeric values where I need to find all implied values.